# How to match a corpus with a string of words using a TF-IDF matrix?

Tags: nlp, text-classification, tfidf

I am trying to match strings of words with a website that has bulletpoints whose text is most similar to it. The way I thought of doing it is to get all of the documents from each bulletpoint into one corpus per website, that I would like to match a string of words with, discard stop words, and then lemmatize everything. Then, for each string of text, I create a TF-IDF sparse matrix, with each row the text from a single bulletpoint from a single website, so that the matrix contains all the text from the bulletpoints from all the websites, as well as a row for the string of words I want to match.

How should I then decide which row my string of words is most similar to? Should I get the cosine similarity of every row with my string of words row and just take whatever one has the highest cosine similarity (I will have a way of identifying the row with the website it was scrapped from)? Or is there an actual formalized way to go about this once I have my sparse matrix?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe looks very close to standard information retrieval: given a predefined set of documents $D$ and an input string $s$, find the most similar document $d\in D$ to $s$ (alternatively find the top $n$ documents $d$ most similar to $s$).

The approach you describe is good, except that in general the input string $s$ is not part of the TFIDF matrix: indeed the full set of predefined documents is encoded as a TFIDF matrix, but then any input string $s$ is simply encoded using the same vocabulary and weights. The advantage is that you don't need to recompute the matrix for every different string $s$ (the matrix can be pre-computed and stored for efficiency reasons). There is no disadvantage because any word in $s$ which is not in the vocabulary cannot be used in the calculation of the similarity anyway.

Indeed the standard method for matching or ranking the documents with respect to $s$ is to calculate a similarity score (e.g. cosine) for every $d$ against $s$, and then pick the highest similarity score.

Comment: Thank you. How do I encode the input string $s$? What are weights in a TF-IDF matrix?

Comment: @sangstar if you're using python you could encode the set of documents with [`TfidfVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) using `fit_transform`. Then to encode a new string $s$ you would use [`transform`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.transform), which applies the vocabulary and weights obtained before.

Comment: The weights are the regular [TFIDF values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf): for every word it's the product of its Term Frequency (TF) and Inverse Document Frequency (IDF) values. If you want you could implement your own functions to calculate the TFIDF matrix, it's not too complex and it's a good way to understand how TFIDF actually works.

Comment: Ah, so I would obtain my weights with `fit_transform` and then can encode a new string with `transform(s)`? This will tell me which row had the highest similarity score?

Comment: @sangstar No, this step only encodes $s$ using the same encoding as the matrix of documents in order to make them comparable. Once this is done you still have to calculate the cosine similarity (for instance) between the encoded $s$ and every document $d$ in the matrix.

Comment: Okay, so when it's encoded, is it now a row in my matrix? How do I reference it using `TfidfVectorizer` to find the cosine singularity between it and each predefined document row?

Comment: @sangstar you can simply access the matrix by row, for example `m[i]` for accessing the doc at index $i$ (see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449127/sklearn-tfidf-transformer-how-to-get-tf-idf-values-of-given-words-in-documen)). If you don't have a lot of experience with sklearn and text, maybe you should start by familiarizing yourself with the concepts and methods. Also sklearn is not the only option, if you are used to a different language/library you should probably use that instead.

Comment: I know that I can access a matrix by row with `m[i]` but which row of the TF-IDF matrix will contain the encoded $s$? Is it just appended as a new row at the bottom, so it's the last row, `m[-1]`? If I'm understanding you correctly, `transform(s)` encodes $s$ into a feature vector, so that it can be used to find the cosine similarity with it and another vector. Are you saying it's not added to the matrix -- it just is converted to a feature vector with the encoding from the TF-IDF matrix?

Comment: @sangstar as I said in my answer, there's no need for the string $s$ to be added to the matrix, it can be represented on its own: `encoded_s = vectorizer.transform(s)`. Then you can loop over the docs in the matrix and compare each of them against `encoded_s`.

Comment: yes I understand now. I can just take the cosine similarity of each row in the matrix with `encoded_s.toarray()`.

Comment: What if more than one row has the highest cosine similarity score?

Comment: @sangstar depends on your design, but normally the result should show all the rows which reach max score. Actually results are often presented as "top 10 most similar" for instance. If there's no way to do this, then one must be picked arbitrarily.